# AzureAD Full Roster Report with Employee ID and Manager

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm having issues with optimizing this PowerShell script.  It's currently taking 8 hours to complete.  I know the issue is the Get-AllAzureADUsers Function due to the ForEach formula.  I am wanting to speed this up by only needing it to query the data stored in a variable instead of the system for all 80k users in our tenant but am struggling with this.  I'm still new to powershell but need this to pull reports on a weekly basis and really am hoping to try to cut this run time down.

```
param (
    [string]$path = "C:\Temp\ADUsers-$((Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy").ToString()).csv"

Function Get-Users{
   process {
      $properties = @(
         'ObjectId',
         '@{N="EmployeeId";E={_.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]}',
         'DisplayName',
         'Surname',
         'givenName',
         'UserPrincipalName',
         'JobTitle',
         'CompanyName'
         '@{N="License":E={$_.ExtensionProperty["extension_a92a_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1"]}
       )
       Get-AzureADUser -Full $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true' | select $properties
    }
}

Function Get-AllAzureADUsers {
    process {
        $users = @()
        $users =+ Get-Users
        $users | ForEach {
             $manager = Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $_.ObjectId | Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName

             [pscustomobject]@{
             "Employee ID" = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $_.ObjectId).ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]
             "First Name" = $_.surname
             "Last Name" = $_.givenName
             "Work Email" = $_.UserPrincipalName
             "Job Title" = $_.JobTitle
             "Department" = $_.CompanyName
             "Manager Email" = $manager
             "License" = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).ExtensionProperty["extension_a92a_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1"]
             }
         }
     }
}
Get-AllAzureADUsers | Sort-Object Name | Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your code can be reduced to this:

```
param(
    [string] $path = "C:\Temp\ADUsers-$(Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy").csv"
)

& {
    foreach($azuser in Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "Employee ID"   = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]
            "First Name"    = $azuser.surname
            "Last Name"     = $azuser.givenName
            "Work Email"    = $azuser.UserPrincipalName
            "Job Title"     = $azuser.JobTitle
            "Department"    = $azuser.CompanyName
            "Manager Email" = (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $azuser.ObjectId).UserPrincipalName
            "License"       = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["extension_a92a_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1"]
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
```

The main reason is taking so long is because you're querying all Enabled users in your `Get-Users` function then you're querying them again 2 more times on your `Get-AllAzureADUsers` function. You can also query and construct the desired output all at once.

You're also sorting by `Name` (`Sort-Object Name`) but your `Get-AllAzureADUsers` function is not returning an object with that property, hence is not doing anything but enumerating all output.

Lastly, you're using `ForEach-Object` for enumerating all users, which is likely the slowest loop in PowerShell.

Comment: This cut the run time in half and don't seem to see any issues.  Thank you.

Comment: that's good to know @KyleDrew thank you for accepting the answer and happy to help.